# generate string and check if it exists in Database then use it

Tags: sql

I have two tables.

```
Table1
------
ID(identity column)
Name
FC

Table2 
------
ID
Name
```

I need to insert the values for Table1 from  Table2

Table 2 will have 1000 records.

So I am using insert sql server 2008 statement.

I an using

```
insert into Table1(Name,FC)

 select Name, SELECT  value  as FC from Table2
```

The value in FC should be generated manually.

I need to check the value generated in FC does not already exists in the database.if it is it should create a new value for FC and insert

I am working  on scalar functions.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by 'The value in `FC` should be generated manually'? Do you mean that `FC` is user supplied?

Comment: This is very unclear so far. This in particular: `SELECT value AS FC FROM Table2` - well, according to your earlier description, `Table2` doesn't have a `value` column. Do you mean that `value` is a name that should be looked up in `Table2` and the corresponding `Table2.ID` should be returned as the new `FC` to insert into `Table1`? And if the value was not found, it would first be inserted into `Table2`, then the new `Table2.ID` would be used as `FC`?

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, you can use unique Identifier i.e. NEWID() in sql server....The major advantage of using GUIDs is that they are unique across all space and time. This comes in handy if you're consolidating records from multiple SQL Servers into one table, as in a data warehousing situation. GUIDs are also used heavily by SQL Server replication to keep track of rows when they're spread out among multiple SQL Servers....

You can implement guid in your query by following way.......

```
       INSERT INTO Table1(Name,FC)SELECT Name, NEWID() from Table2
```